# Is there something like "uptime" in telebot library python

Tags: python, telebot

I kinda want to make admin panel in my bot where uptime will be displayed, is there something like this in telebot lib?

At first i wanted to make it my own way, but i tought - "maybe there is something like this in telebot library"

Comment: Well, did you look at the library's documentation? What did you find? See also [ask]

Comment: yeah, i did, but couldnt find anything